# App Links Assistant Android Studio open in first app activity

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-app-links

I use the 'App Links Assistant' in Android Studio to configure links that will be opened through my app.

Everything works well.

But my problem is that when I open the link through the app, it opens the activity defined within the previous app where I clicked on the link.

For example:

If I click on a link in WhatsApp I see something like this:

[image: open link]

And when I open using the app, the app opens within WhatsApp as seen in this image:

[image: whatsapp opens]

So how can I open the app only in My app and not within WhatsApp or another app?

Here my AndroidManifest.xml code of this activity:

```
 <activity android:name=".extraLinks"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.jtube.live" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="www.jtube.live" />
        </intent-filter>
       
    </activity>
```

**update: I checked my Gmail and Chrome apps and if I open from those apps its working well, so my problem with Whatsapp app only...**

Comment: Everybody can help? I cant find answer!

Comment: Please, provide a definition in AndroidManifest.xml for an activity to which URL was mapped.

Comment: @НиколайГольцев I added code from manifest I will be happy for you help!

Comment: Did you try to open your app through a link from another app, e.g Gmail? I can't replicate this behavior.

Comment: @НиколайГольцев yes, from gmail and chrome its working well! I don't know what todo:(

Comment: This is likely because yours is a browser app. Which is why I see Chrome as the other choice. 

This happens if you open any app and you click a link that tries to open a browser. 

If you chose Chrome I feel you'll get the same result. Like I do when I open a link on LinkedIn App it opens it as a webpage but within the LinkedIn app itself. 

If yours was a native app that wasn't a browser, let's say a payment app or a game, it would open it as a separate app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When activity A starts activity B the default behavior is:

A new instance of activity B is created within a current task and pushed to the back stack.

To customize such behavior there are some options:

- add flags to the intent that starts a specific activity;
- set `launchMode` attribute for an activity being started;

The first option is out of your control when we talk about other applications.

You face different behavior within WhatsApp and Gmail applications because of the following:

Gmail customizes intents for every HTTP link with [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) and consequently, activity in your application starts within a new task. WhatsApp application doesn't specify this flag when it starts any activity which handles a specific HTTP link.

In your case, the only way to customize this behavior is to play with `launchMode` attribute for target activity that handles the app link. There are two possible values applicable to your case: `singleTask` or `singleInstance`.

Check these links to understand how it works:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack ;
- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode ;

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<intent-filter android:label="app_label">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
       android:scheme="https"
       android:host="www.jtube.live" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I tried with your recent upadte and its yet not working